# Incrementing dictionary values always ends up in sum

Tags: python, dictionary

If I'm reading a variety of objects and increment the value of its corresponding dictionary keys (for example, category), where the values of the dictionary is a list, all the dictionary entries end up with the same value, which is the sum of all the values instead of the expected ones. This won't happen if the value of the dictionary is a float/int instead of a list.

```
category_dict = dict(zip(category_list,[0,0]*len(category_list)))
for item in data:
    i = item['Type']:
    category_dict[i][0] += item['Amount']
```

The result looks like :

```
{item1: 98999, item2: 98999, item3: 98999...}
```

where `98999` is the sum of all the amounts.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `category_dict = dict.fromkeys(category_list, 0)` would be a lot more readable.

Comment: What `category_list` looks like? And what is `data`? Please provide working and meaningful code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It would be not only more readable, but also correct because the OP is stuffing into `category_dict` only references to _the same `[0,0]` list_ and of course when he increments a value, all the values of the dictionary are incremented as well.

Comment: @gboffi: no, the `[0, 0] * integer_value` result is one list with `2 * integer_value` zeros in it. You are thinking of `[[0, 0]] * integer_value`, which creates an outer list with `integer_value` references to one nested list object. `zip()` will only look at the first half of this list, zipping the values of `category_list` with those zeros, so you get the same output as my `dict.fromkeys()` call.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're correct (of course) but then I don't see how the OP can execute her/his code: I have tested (too late...) the code and `category_dict[i][0]` gives me a `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`. Otoh, the behaviour that the OP reports is typical of updating the same mutable object referenced by many names/keys... What I mean, is it possible that the actual code, not what was posted, is `[[0,0]]*n`?

Comment: @gboffi: which is why the post is downvoted an attracting so many comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a defaultdict:

```
category_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)
for item in data:
    cat = item['Type']
    n = item['Amount']
    category_dict[cat] += n
```

This should give you something like:

```
{item1: 53, item2: 12, item3: 4...}
```

I'm not quite certain that is what you want though. 
You are talking about a list per category, but you only use [0] of that list.

**EDIT:**

If you require a two element list per category you can use:

```
category_dict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: return [0,0])
for item in data:
    cat = item['Type']
    n = item['Amount']
    category_dict[cat][0] += n
```

which should give you something like:

```
{item1: [53,0], item2: [12,0], item3: [4,0]...}
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters IMHO that is not quite clear. Also `category_dict = dict.fromkeys(category_list, 0)` produces exactly the same result.

Answer (score 0):

All the values in your dictionary are the same list. When you increment a value

```
category_dict[i][0] += item['Amount']
```

you're doing the same on all the items in the dictionary

This happens because you instantiate the dictionary like this

```
category_dict = dict(zip(category_list,[0,0]*len(category_list)))
```

and `[0,0]*n` is a list of `n` copies of the same `[0,0]` list

Try instead

```
category_dict = {k:[0,0] for k in category_list}
```

Comment: `[0, 0] * n` produces a list of `n * 2` references to the `0` integers. It doesn't produce a list with references to lists in it. You are thinking of `[[0, 0]] * n` here. Multiplication of a list repeats the *contents* of that list, not produce a new list with the multiplied list repeated in it.

Comment: I should have known it better... I can try to justify my mistake observing that the OP code works _only if_ the value of the dictionary items are lists, as I detailed in a comment under the OPost

Comment: It's ok gboffi, I had this same answer and Martijn down voted it. I decided to delete my answer instead of waiting for the OP to show us his *real* code. But I agree with you that this is his problem. The OP even suggests that his code that he posted doesn't match his real code with the quote "where the values of the dictionary is a list, all the dictionary entries end up with the same value, which is the sum of all the values instead of the expected ones. This won't happen if the value of the dictionary is a float/int instead of a list."